# How can I fill in every second block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit

How would I fill in every other block with a smooth Stone Slab? I want it to be like

```
oioioioioioioioioioioioioio
```

Where:

- o = air
- i = stone slab

Comment: "Every other block" in what area? In the whole world? In a specific area? And do you want this to be stacked horizontally or vertically?

Comment: On top of what Ben asks - what have you tried so far?

Comment: The `clone` command will be your friend. Look it up in the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what exactly you want to do with the slabs the correct answer was already given: the `clone` command will be your friend.

Basically it's `/clone x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3`, where 1 and 2 are your boundaries of what you want to clone and 3 is the target area, which in your case can as well be `~ ~ ~`, but we'll come to that later.

Let's say you want to copy some slabs like these:
[image]

1. Note the coordinates of the two outside stones. These will be the boundaries.
2. If you want to clone the stones *upwards* (East or South where the coords go up) you can simply do this:

   - stand next to the last slab (leave one space for air if you didn't copy one after the last slab)
   - Use the `clone` command: `/clone x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 ~ ~ ~`
     (In my case: `/clone -627 4 -341 -643 4 -341  ~ ~ ~`)
3. If you need to clone to the other direction (West, North) it is important to *subtract* the length of the source area from the target coords:

   - `clone` will always go upwards, so you need to start further down
   - Let's say I have 143 blocks to clone (-643 to -501):
     `/clone -501 4 -341 -643 4 -341  ~-143 ~ ~`
4. Use the new boundary stone slab's coords and clone it again: `/clone NEWx1 y1 NEWz1 x2 y2 z2 ~(-length) ~ ~(-length)`

This way you can clone more and faster until you're happy with the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the idea. (Really I just copied a row of like 100 of them and pasted them so I found that also works) I don't really understand this way really xD

Comment: @DanielALlen WorldEdit? That would be a really easy way to accomplish that :P